# Search file contents recursively when know where in file

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find, xargs

I am interested in efficiently searching files for content using bash and related tools (eg sed, grep), in the specific case that I have additional information about where in the file the intended content is.  For example, I want to replace a particular string in line #3 of each file that contains a specific string on line 3 of the file.  Therefore, I don't want to do a recursive `grep -r` on the whole directory as that would search the entirety of each file, wasting time since I know that the string of interest is on line #3, if it is there. This full-grep approach could be done with `grep -rl 'string_to_find_in_files' base_directory_to_search_recursively`.  Instead I am thinking about using `sed -i ".bak" '3s/string_to_replace/string_to_replace_with' files` to search only on line #3 of all files recursively in a directory, however sed seems to only be able to take one file as input argument.  How can I apply sed to multiple files recursively?  `find -exec {} \;` and `find -print0 | xargs -0` seem to be very slow.. Is there a faster method than using find?  I can achieve the desired effect very quickly with `awk` but only on a single directory, it does not seem to me to be recursive, such as using `awk 'FNR==3{print $0}' directory/*`.  Any way to make this recursive?  Thanks.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/funroll/5504098

Comment: this does not demonstrate recursion, it would if you called sed on the directory `tmp`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` to have the list of files and feed to `sed` or `awk` one by one by `xargs`

for example, this will print the first lines of all files listed by find.

```
$ find . -name "*.csv" | xargs -L 1 sed -n '1p'
```

Comment: Seems very slow to me, I am asking if there is a faster way of achieving this by relying purely on `sed` (or `awk`, or a line-specific call to `grep`, etc).  Thanks though

Comment: Do you have any timings data of alternative approaches?